# Fan always running at full speed

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I am having the issue that whenever I turn on Ubuntu (I'm using dual-boot with Windows 10), fans in my notebook will always run at full speed even when I'm not doing anything. The same thing happens on every Linux distro I had, but on Windows it's not doing so.

My notebook: Acer E5-575G-5328

I tried those common resolutions as to change the GRUB setting to make it equal to acpi_osi=!Windows 2012, but it didn't work. I am really getting annoyed by listening to the fans always spinning.

Please, can somebody give me a working resolution to this issue?

Thank you

EDIT: This is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HD Graphics 520
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Any other suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try also the following:

try looking at the output for firmware interrupts:

```
grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts
```

You'll get a whole block of different outputs, for example:

```
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe01:19241984   enabled
```

Should you encounter any one of these, with a large number following gpexy: and it being enabled, try disabling it in crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

i suggest you use nano for editing. Then add it:

```
@reboot echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe01
```

with gpe01 being replaced with interrupts according to your previous output.

Reboot and see if it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I do not have such high values in my output, the maximum is 72, disabled and then there is 63, enabled. So, the values are low.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nvidia adapter is always in use. Run

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Then log of and log on.

The fan should stop.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it didn't work. I tried to apply this command, logged out, powered off my notebook, restarted it, but still the fans are running at full speed.

Comment: sudo prime-select intel
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'nvidia-340']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Info: selecting nvidia-340-prime for the intel profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode